# Why this is "assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]"

Tags: c, pointers

Recently I study C and there is what I can't understand.

 I knew and found that gets( ) function returns *char **.

`char * gets(char *buffer)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[20], *p;
    p = gets(str) /* <- gcc said warning: assignment ~. */
}
```

definitely `p` is `char *` type and the return type of `gets( )` is also `char *`. 
Then why gcc said warning:

> assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion] ?

Well it's working... but I just expected compiling with no any messages.

**Edit:**

1. `char * gets(char *buffer)` was exist but now **removed** from language.
2. But it is still in library.
3. Then ,with implicit declaration,`gets` is compiled with default return value `int`.
4. Though `gets` works well, It's very dangerous to use. Now `fgets` much better choice than `gets`

In addtion, I wanna know that how `gets` is exist on header file.

> #if __CLIBC_USE (DEPRECATED_GETS) 
> /* Get a newline-terminated string from stdin, removing the newline. 
>     This function is impossible to use safely. It has been officially removed from ISO c11 and ISO c++14, and we have also removed it from the _GNU_SOURCE feature list. It remains available when explicitly using an old ISO C, Unix, or POSIX standard. 
>     This function is a possible cancellation point and therefore not marked with __THROW.   */ 
> `extern char *gets (char *__s) __wur __attribute_deprecated__;`
> #endif

I could understand #ifdef that comments told me and how function is declared to be used.

Thank you for everyone! (_ _ )

Comment: Never ***ever*** use the `gets` function. It's so [dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used) it has even been removed from the C language. Use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead. Any learning or teaching resource using `gets` should be looked at with great suspicion.

Comment: `gets()` has been removed from the language, you may be using a version that doesn't have it declared, so you're getting the default `int` declaration.

Comment: @Barmar Was `gets` removed? Then how can I use the function that doesn't declared?

Comment: It's still in the C library because it needs to be compatible with multiple versions of C. But depending on the version you're compiling for, it may be removed from the header file with `#ifdef`.

Comment: Did you get another warning `implicit declaration of function 'gets'; `?

Comment: @Jabberwocky oh yes I also get that.

Answer (score 3):

You certainly got another warning `warning: implicit declaration of function 'gets';`.

That means that the compiler didn't find the definition of `gets` (presumably because it has been removed from the language about 10 years ago). Therefore it assumes that `gets` is a function that returns an `int` and `p = gets(str)` would then assign an `int` to a pointer, hence the second warning `assignment to ‘char *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast`.

If you see warnings containing the word "implicit", consider them as an error.

And "makes pointer without a cast" warnings are almost always actually errors.

I suggest you use `fgets` instead, but be aware that with `fgets` your line ends usually with a `\n` (that can be removed easily, for more details read this: [Removing trailing newline character from fgets() input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input))